# During install, not partitioning correctly

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I'm trying to install the latest 64-bit build of Ubuntu (13.04). Unfortunately, during install Ubuntu can't seem to partition my drive correctly.

My primary drive is a 128GB SSD. I want it dual booting with Windows 7.

With Windows 7, I resized my primary NTFS Windows partition to create 20GB of free space. When I select that free space for Ubuntu to install on, I receive the following warning:

```
Some of the partitions you created are too small. 
Please make the following partitions at least this large: /2.9 GB  
If you do not go back to the partitioner and increase the size of these partitions the installation may fail.
```

However, I do not know which partition it's asking me to resize.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Please boot into the Live CD/DVD/USB and add to your Q the result of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: I got this message while creating a virtual machine with a 20GB disk and 16GB of RAM.  The swap was automatically allocated at 16GB, leaving only 4GB for the root partition.  The solution was to manually adjust the partitions (using the "Something else" option) to reduce/remove the swap allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried choosing manual install and manually reformatting free space?

Basically follow this guide : http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/02/manual-advanced-partitioning-in-ubuntu.html

Summary:

1. Make two partitions from free space, one primary ext4 mount at /, one primary linux swap.
2. Choose /dev/sda to install GRUB on.
3. Continue with install.