# Ubuntu partitioning issues

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to follow these instructions to get my computer to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu. I followed [these instructions](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/dual-boot-ubuntu-15-04-14-10-and-windows-10-8-1-8-step-by-step-tutorial-with-screenshots) , but when I tried to go through with it, I got an warning saying my home was too small and that it should be size '0TB0'. What gives?

Here's an image of what I got, for reference:

[image]

I'm using the latest version, which I think is 16.04.1. How do I boot in UEFI boot mode? I've been just doing pressing Enter on startup and then pressing F12 (which is something like boot up from temporary device), and selecting the USB from there.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? It looks like Windows is UEFI, are you installing Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? Otherwise it may complain about a missing bios_grub partition for BIOS boot, which you do not want if Windows is UEFI.

Comment: I'm just using the latest version, which I think is 16.04.1. How do I boot in UEFI boot mode? I've been just doing pressing enter on startup and then picking F12 (which is something like boot up from temporary device), and picking the USB from there.

Comment: Can you type the exact error message?  Your picture cut the message off.

Comment: It was "Some of the partitions you created are too small. (...)
If you do not go back to the partitioner and increase the size of these partitions the installation may fail."

Comment: @T.Smit Home doesn't appear to be small.  There appears to be something else after too small.  It's cut off from the image.  You mentioned "...".  I'm wondering what that entire line is saying.  Looking at the image, I don't see a problem with the partitions.  But if I knew what the entire line was saying exactly it could shed some light on the problem.  If you respond to this comment and put @(my userid) I'll get a notice there's response.  Otherwise it might take me a long time to check this thread to see if there is a respond.

Comment: @L.D.James The rest of the line said "Please make the following partitions at least this large: " (at least, I'm pretty sure it's the same message as from here http://askubuntu.com/questions/353926/during-install-not-partitioning-correctly ), and the only one it listed was the home partition.

Comment: Thanks.  I gave the procedure to resolve your issue in a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [this ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook). Has plenty of details on UEFI and dualbooting. It has instructions for both ways, but advises you to install GRUB (and Ubuntu) before installing windows. Because of the way windows "works" ;-).

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: I believe if a person is going to run both Ubuntu and Windows, they might best install Windows first.  Installing Ubuntu second it'll install grub and it'll see Windows and automatically add both installations to the boot menu.  If you install Ubuntu and then install Wndows.  You'll have to run routines to fix Ubuntu because Windows won't install support for Ubuntu.  Ubuntu will install support for Windows.  ...support being, it'll have both OSes listed in the boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the information that I can gather from the image and your comments, there is a problem with your `/home` and root `/` allocation.  You can remedy this by deleting both and making one big partition between the two.  Don't split root and home.  Specify the one big partition as root `/`.  You'll automatically have a `/home` folder with the install.  Just as with your Windows install... it creates a `/users/yourname` home directory.

As far as installing, make sure that you boot into the `UEFI` mode.  The windows installer will recognize this and give you support for the way your previous OS was already installed.  If you try to install it in a different mode you might not have the multiple choice when booting your computer.  You might have to spend time fixing it.  Running Ubuntu install under `UEFI` and it'll be installed properly initially.

This answer is assuming that your Windows is already install in `UEFI`.  If Windows isn't install `UEFI`, then Ubuntu shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot and post after I try this.